# Kext com.apple.driver.AppleSDXC not present in HighSierra

Tags: high-sierra

I am trying to remount the SD card after eject using

```
sudo kextunload -b com.apple.driver.AppleSDXC
sudo kextload -b com.apple.driver.AppleSDXC
```

but it says `Kext com.apple.driver.AppleSDXC not found for unload request`

I am on macOS HighSierra

```
sudo kextunload -v 6 -b com.apple.driver.AppleSDXC
Kext user-space log filter changed from 0xff2 to 0xfff.
Kext kernel-space log filter changed from 0xff2 to 0xfff.
Requesting unload of com.apple.driver.AppleSDXC (with termnation of IOServices).
(kernel) User-space log flags changed from 0x0 to 0xfff.
(kernel) Received 'Unload' request from user space.
(kernel) Kext com.apple.driver.AppleSDXC not found for unload request.
Kernel error handling kext request - (libkern/kext) not found.
Failed to unload com.apple.driver.AppleSDXC - (libkern/kext) not found.
```

Comment: What is the output if you add a `-v 6 ` before the -b ? Have you also checked the system/kernel logs?

Comment: The file /System/Library/Extensions/AppleSDXC.kext should exist just fine? It's SIP protected so unless you disabled that the file can't really be gone.

Comment: Yep, I remember, I have disabled SIP long back but now I get the same error after I have enabled it.